# Zero Effort Miss missile guidance doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, math

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02APHAyHRMI&list=PLcmbTy9X3gXt02z1wNy4KF5ui0tKxdQm7) course and implemented [formula](https://youtu.be/CMOh2xWk_qA?t=567) like this

```py
def ZEM_3d(pursuer, target, N=3):
    dR = target.pos - pursuer.pos
    dV = target.vel - pursuer.vel

    R = np.sqrt(dR.dot(dR))
    V = np.sqrt(dV.dot(dV))

    if V == 0: V = 1e-16  # if target is stationary and initial speed is 0

    t_go = R / V  # time to go

    ZEM_i = dR + dV * t_go  # ZEM at t
    LOS_u = dR / R  # LOS direction unit vector
    ZEM_n = ZEM_i - ZEM_i.dot(LOS_u) * LOS_u  # ZEM normal to LOS

    nL = N * ZEM_n/(t_go * t_go)

    return {
        "nL": nL,
        "R": R,
        "V": V,
        "t_go": t_go,
        "ZEM_i": ZEM_i,
        "ZEM_n": ZEM_n,
    }
```

And simulation is something like this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("GTK3Agg")

def rot_to_unit(yaw, pitch):
    return np.array([
            np.cos(yaw) * np.cos(pitch),
            np.sin(yaw) * np.cos(pitch),
            np.sin(pitch)
        ], dtype=float)

class HeadingVelocity3d:
    # yaw, pitch
    def __init__(self, yaw, pitch, pos, V):
        self._yaw = yaw
        self._pitch = pitch
        self.pos = np.array(pos, dtype=float)
        self.vel = rot_to_unit(yaw, pitch) * V
        self._V = V

    @property
    def yaw(self):
        return self._yaw
    @yaw.setter
    def yaw(self, value):
        self._yaw = value
        self.vel = rot_to_unit(value, self.pitch) * self.V

    @property
    def pitch(self):
        return self._pitch
    @pitch.setter
    def pitch(self, value):
        self._pitch = value
        self.vel = rot_to_unit(self.yaw, value) * self.V

    @property
    def V(self):
        return self._V
    @V.setter
    def V(self, value):
        self._V = value
        self.vel = rot_to_unit(self.yaw, self.pitch) * value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = 10

    pursuer = HeadingVelocity3d(np.deg2rad(0), 0, np.array([0, 0, 0]), g*3)
    target = HeadingVelocity3d(np.deg2rad(0), 0, np.array([100, 100, 100]), g*1)
    dt = 1. / 20
    N = 5

    max_sim_time = 20

    t = 0

    log = {'pursuer': [], 'target': []}
    while True:
        ret = ZEM_3d(pursuer, target, N=N)
        nL = ret['nL']
        R = ret['R']

        t = t + dt
        if R <= 1 or t > max_sim_time:
            break

        pursuer.pos += pursuer.vel * dt

        target.pos += target.vel * dt

        pursuer.vel += nL * dt  # velocity update

        # target maneuver
        target.yaw = np.cos(t * 5)
        target.pitch = np.cos(t / 2.)

        log["pursuer"].append(list(pursuer.pos))
        log['target'].append(list(target.pos))

    distance = [np.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2 + (z1 - z2) ** 2) for (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2) in
                zip(log["pursuer"], log["target"])]

    print(min(distance))

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

    px, py, pz = [], [], []
    for x, y, z in log["pursuer"]: px.append(x); py.append(y); pz.append(z)

    tx, ty, tz = [], [], []
    for x, y, z in log["target"]: tx.append(x); ty.append(y); tz.append(z)

    ax.scatter(px, pz, py, c=range(len(distance)), cmap=matplotlib.colormaps["Greens"])
    ax.scatter(tx, tz, ty, c=range(len(distance)), cmap=matplotlib.colormaps["Reds"])

    plt.show()
```

And it works for when pursuer.pos[0] < target.pos[0], but when it exceeds that, pursuer starts to go away from the target. Like, when pursuer.pos[0] < target.pos[0] [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGWz.png) and when pursuer.pos[0] > target.pos[0] [doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWHaW.png).

I'm not exactly good at mathematics so I just tried to swap target and pursuer positions and velocities, and do opposite of what guidance said, but that's didn't work. I also tried to rotate x and z coodrinates and velocities and then rotate the output back, but this also didn't work.